# how to add a string at the end of pointer to pointer (**pointer) in C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to add a string at the end of pointer to pointer in C, I'm using the below code the problem is I can't free what I have allocated as the pointer to pointer has values that were not all allocated memory, How can I add string at the end of a pointer to pointer properly?

```
int     add_environ(char *str, char **envp)
{
    char    **r;
    int     i;

    r = envp;
    i = 0;
    while (r[i])
   {
        i++;
    }
 //how can I add string without using malloc?
// my problem is I can't free this allocated memory
    r[i] = malloc(strlen(str)); 
    if (r[i])
    {
        r[i] = str;
        r[++i] = 0;
        return (1);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: As for me then I have understood nothing.

Comment: Are you trying to simulate `setenv()` or `putenv()` and modifying the environment, or are you manipulating a structure that looks like an environment list, or is the choice of `envp` accidental and you're just manipulating an array of `char *`? You'll need to know how the array is managed — whether your code is in charge of it or not — and you will need to reallocate more space sometimes. You need to tell the calling code where the array of `char *` is located.  You might pass a `char ***` to the function, or return the start every time: `char **add_environ(const char *str, char **envp)`.

Comment: The question is confusing. In description you have asked how to add new string pointer to envp and in code there is a comment about how to free allocated memory. Answer to which question are you expecting here?

Comment: Like I said in the description my problem is, I can't free the allocated memory, and I want to know if the is a better way, as with this code I can't free the allocated memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question only targets environmental variables, then I would go with `setenv`. If not, Waxrat gave you one solution. Oh, btw: You're assuming in your code, that `envp` is arbitrarily long. That's not true either, so your code will crash sooner or later. Depending on your exact requirements, I would suggest to create a deep copy of `envp` in `main` and then only operate on that copy, because then everything is `malloc`ed and needs to be `free`d, so nothing special to track any longer.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to remember somehow which items in the *envp array came from the heap. For example, by storing them in another array of pointers. There's no real general way to do what you describe, you'd need to do something context specific.